# what does system.exception does not contain a definition for Response?

Tags: c#, ftp

I am new to Programming. I am developing a ftp application. 
For that I need to find files in ftp is existing or not. I have written the below code for finding the file existence.. But an error occurred

`System.exception` does not contain a definition for Response

```
catch (WebException ex)    
    {    
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;    
        if (response.StatusCode ==           FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable)    
            return false;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your full code is

```
        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create
("ftp://ftp.domain.com/doesntexist.txt");
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

        try
        {
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            if (response.StatusCode ==
                FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable)
            {
                //Does not exist
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
```

Do you try to add all namespaces, espessially

```
using System.Net;
```

Comment: `catch (WebException ex)` Check out it again. you write exact it, not `catch (Exception ex)` ?